# Нужно ли указывать пароль базы данных в settings.py Django?

Tags: django

БД - PostgreSQL (это чтобы про SQL Lite не подумал никто).

Где-то вычитал, что лучше не вписывать в settings.py в строке PASSWORD пароль от базы. Собственно объяснения источник не дал, а вопрос остался.

Надеюсь кто-нибудь разъяснит. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если выкладывать исходники сайта на гитхаб, то вряд ли захочется, чтобы там были пароли :) Вот примерно поэтому лучше не вписывать

Comment: @andreymal В ином случае оставлять его более-менее безопасно?

Comment: если никому settings.py не показывать, то безопасно. Но всё равно советую не лениться, делать как все и разделять) С SECRET_KEY и прочими секретными настройками аналогично

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, хранить пароль от БД и `SECRET_KEY` прямо в коде `settings.py` считается плохой практикой.
Как правило, используются переменные окружения системы (кроме случаев, когда используется `apache2` в качестве веб-сервера, так как у него отдельное окружение), либо хранят в неверсионируемом файле.

Пример использования переменных окружения из книги `2 scoops of Django`:

```
# into your settings, but ImproperlyConfigured is an exception. 
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured 

def get_env_variable(var_name): 
    """Get the environment variable or return exception.""" 
    try: 
        return os.environ[var_name] 
    except KeyError: 
        error_msg = 'Set the {} environment variable'.format(var_name) 
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

SOME_SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable('SOME_SECRET_KEY')
```

Лично у меня как раз `apache2`, поэтому я пошёл по другому пути, предложенному в этой же книге в качестве альтернативы: маленький неверсионируемый текстовый файл, в идеале --- с правами на чтение только у сайта. Сам файл хранится у админов и подкладывается при развертывании сайта.

Например, у меня следующая реализация:

Фрагмент `settings.py`:

```
...
from settings.private import PrivateConfig

prv = PrivateConfig('private.json')
SECRET_KEY = prv.get('SECRET_KEY')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': prv.get('DATABASE', 'NAME'),
        'USER': prv.get('DATABASE', 'USER'),
        'PASSWORD': prv.get('DATABASE', 'PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': prv.get('DATABASE', 'HOST'),
        'PORT': prv.get('DATABASE', 'PORT'),
    },
}
...
```

`private.json`:

```
{
  "SECRET_KEY": "<value>",
  "DATABASE": {
    "NAME": "<value>",
    "USER": "<value>",
    "PASSWORD": "<value>",
    "HOST": "<value>",
    "PORT": "<value>"
  }
}
```

`private.py`:

```
import json

from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured


class PrivateConfig(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path = path
        self._check_path()
        self._config = None
        self._read()

    def _check_path(self):
        pass

    def _read(self):
        try:
            with open(self._path) as f:
                self._config = json.loads(f.read())
        except FileNotFoundError:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Error opening private config file at '{}'".format(self._path)
            )

    def get(self, key, subkey=None):
        try:
            if subkey is not None:
                return self._config[key][subkey]
            else:
                return self._config[key]
        except KeyError:
            error_msg = "Private JSON-file has not key '{0}'".format(key)
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

Comment: В моем случае nginx. Т.е. добавить первый пример в settings.py, заменив значение SOME_SECRET_KEY на свое?

Comment: @Jimmy, т.е. чтобы использовать переменные окружения `SOME_SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable('SOME_SECRET_KEY')`? Да, для каждого параметра (`SECRET_KEY`, пароль БД и иные) задать в системе переменную окружения с именем, совпадающим с аргументом внутри `get_env_variable()`.