# Как сделать несколько конфигураций (settings.py) для проекта Django?

Tags: python, django

Довольно очевидно, что, например, на продакшене и при разработке конфигурация проекта должна быть разная. Однако по умолчанию Django предусматривает использование одного-единственного `settings.py`, в котором лежит всё подряд, без каких-либо намёков на разделение. А разделить хочется.

Например, при разработке можно включить `DEBUG = True` и подключить Debug Toolbar, чего на продакшене делать нельзя, использовать какую-то конкретную локальную базу данных разработчика, смягчить ограничения и т.д.

Кроме того, если захочется опубликовать Django-проект на каком-нибудь гитхабе, то добавлять в репозиторий `settings.py` со всеми паролями совсем не круто. А если удалять оттуда пароли, коммитить и возвращать пароли обратно, то это всё совершенно неудобно, и можно случайно забыть это и закоммитить `settings.py` с паролями. Да и конфликты будут.

Как можно разделить конфигурацию на разные части, чтобы параметры продакшена, параметры разработки и пароли лежали как-то отдельно друг от друга?

Comment: Эта тема уже частично упоминалась [там](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/251697) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728740), но по-моему более обширный и ёмкий вопрос-ответ будет полезен

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В интернете водится несколько всяких разных способов разделения конфигурации Django, но самым лучшим мне кажется разделение через модули и `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Запуск Django начинается с чтения Python-модуля с настройками, и имя нужного модуля должен быть указан в переменной окружения `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` — без него Django просто не запустится.  Чтобы разработчику было проще жить, команда `django-admin startproject` автоматически прописывает `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` со значением вида `yourproject.settings` в файлы `manage.py`, `wsgi.py` и `asgi.py`. Таким образом, меняя значение `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, мы можем переключаться между разными файлами настроек.

Чтобы разделить продакшен и разработку, я предлагаю вместо файла `settings.py` использовать каталог `settings` с подмодулями внутри. Структура примерно такая:

```
├─ yourproject/
│  ├─ settings/
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  ├─ base.py
│  │  ├─ development.py
│  │  └─ production.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  └─ asgi.py
│  ├─ models.py
│  ├─ urls.py
│  └─ wsgi.py
├─ local_settings.py
└─ manage.py
```

В файле `base.py` хранятся настройки по умолчанию, общие для всех окружений. В файлах `development.py` и `production.py` хранятся отдельные настройки для разработки и продакшена соответственно. Файла `settings.py` нет вообще.

Содержимое файла `base.py` аналогично обычному `settings.py` — можно его просто переименовать.

В файле `development.py` прописываем штуки, упрощающие разработку и отладку:

```
from .base import *  # подгружаем настройки по умолчанию

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + ['debug_toolbar']
MIDDLEWARE = ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'] + MIDDLEWARE
# и так далее
```

В файле `production.py` прописываем настройки, специфичные для «боевого» окружения:

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['yourproject.example.com']
```

Пароли и секретные ключи здесь не хранятся! Точнее, вы можете прописать в `base.py` базу данных sqlite и какие-нибудь стандартные ключи, но считать их секретными не стоит: идея в том, что все эти файлы могут быть безопасно опубликованы без каких-либо изменений.

Как теперь выбрать нужную конфигурацию? Для начала вспомним, что она уже прописана в файле `manage.py` путём установки значения по умолчанию. Теперь нужно его заменить примерно так:

```
# manage.py
# ... найдите такую строку в файле и обновите её:
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourproject.settings.development")
```

Когда вы хотите выбрать какую-то другую конфигурацию, вам следует заменить переменную окружения `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. Все варианты её замены в разных ОС расписывать не буду, но вот пример (*nix, sh):

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yourproject.settings.development ./manage.py runserver
```

Подключения к базам данных, пароли и секретные ключи следует хранить в файле `local_settings.py`. Этот файл секретен, не должен быть добавлен в репозиторий (для git его нужно прописать в `.gitignore`) и не должен нигде публиковаться. Он может выглядеть примерно так:

```
# Этим импортом вы можете выбирать между development и production
from yourproject.settings.development import *

DATABASES = { ... чтототам ... }
SECRET_KEY = '230eoqd439wej9c0eru384jfsc'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '123456'
# и все остальные секретики
```

Подключить его можно через ту же самую `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=local_settings ./manage.py runserver
```

Однако постоянное прописывание переменной окружения кажется неудобным. Можно прописать `local_settings` точно так же внутри файла `manage.py` и жить спокойно. Однако, возможно, вы захотите, чтобы файл `local_settings.py` был необязателен для работы проекта (как этого захотел я), поэтому можно прописать выбор конфигурации в зависимости от того, существует файл или нет:

```
# manage.py
# ...
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'local_settings.py')):
    # Если рядом с manage.py лежит local_settings.py — используем его
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "local_settings")
else:
    # Если нет — используем стандартные настройки без секретов
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourproject.settings.development")
```

Кроме того, стоит помнить, что `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` также обычно прописан в файле `wsgi.py` (а с версии 3.0 добавился `asgi.py`), и когда вы будете [запускать проект на production с помощью стороннего сервера](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/) (uwsgi, gunicorn, uvicorn и пр.), то стоит провести аналогичные изменения и в этих файлах.

(Впрочем, на мой субъективный взгляд, может оказаться лучше вообще удалить упоминания `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` из `wsgi.py` и `asgi.py` и всегда задавать переменную окружения извне — это повысит контроль над проектом и предотвратит случайный запуск с неправильными настройками.)

Comment: Я для паролей и прочих токенов использую environment variables в конфиге. Очень удобно, хоть с Docker, хоть с Ansible.