# Настройки Django-проекта с открытым исходным кодом

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, github, config

Я разработал небольшой проект на `Django` и хотел бы выложить его в открытый доступ на `GitHub`.

Но дело в том, что файл настроек (`settings.py`) содержит конфиденциальную информацию:

- Секретные ключи
- Хосты
- Пользователи и пароли БД

*и т.д.*

---

Один раз загрузить его без данных значений и добавить в `.gitignore`, я не могу, так как некоторая информация в нём точно будет обновляться по мере разработки.

В данный момент я вручную редактирую и заливаю этот файл (что просто ужасно). А другие разработчики/пользователи (пока что только я), при его обновлении, вынуждены скачивать его с репозитория и заново заполнять своими значениями.

---

***Вопрос:***

> Какие есть удобные и для разработчиков и для пользователей варианты
>   распространения конфигурационных файлов, если в них есть
>   конфиденциальная информация?

Comment: Расскажу как это сделано у нас. Создан файл local_settings.py. В нем вся конфиденциальная информация. Она же импортирована в основной settings.py и добавлена в gitignore.

Comment: @zakiroof А как этот файл между разработчиками распространяется? Приватная ветка?

Comment: Тут уже как вам удобнее. Главное удалить приватные данные из открытого доступа.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как сделать несколько конфигураций (settings.py) для проекта Django?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747839)

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, отличный вопрос/ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для таких случаев есть встроенная библиотека python - [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Создаёте в корне проекта файл config.ini и выносите туда все ваши секретные параметры. Так же можно выносить туда те параметры, которые используются для настройки сервера на локальной машине: хосты, порты, логин и пароль к базе данных и тому-подобное.

Данные файла читаете уже в settings.py, джанго-проекта и раскидываете по константам.

Пример conf.ini:

```
[my_django_project]
secret_key = 6*=jiwnotyve!)34fi^$66d9@4@cw8ra!9asdf2v^v3=feh^5j0zt8*
debug = true

[postgresql]
name_database: django_db
username: django
password: django
```