# Как правильно перенести проект Django на сервер?

Tags: django, ubuntu, git, bitbucket

Проект разрабатывался локально, с локальной БД и локальными настройками в **settings.py**. Теперь нужно его развернуть на сервере. В **.gitignore** включены **settings.py**, а также миграции.

На сервере создано виртуальное окружение, настроена БД. При клонировании репозитория проект оказывается без файла **settings.py**, он добавляется и редактируется вручную на сервере.

Если проект создается на сервере при помощи `django-admin startproject mysite`, проблем нет, однако при описанном выше сценарии файл **settings.py** оказывается "неизвестным" внутри проекта (может быть, есть и какие-то другие проблемы).

Что нужно сделать, чтобы всё работало? (Вопрос именно о благополучии внутри проекта Django, всё остальное настроено.)

ОС на сервере: Ubuntu 16.04, версия Django: 2.2.14, Python 3.5.

Comment: Для начала верните settings.py на место и организуйте хранение настроек более разумным образом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747839

Comment: Ну а так непонятно что такое «оказывается "неизвестным"» и о каких вообще проблемах речь

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас нет конкретной формулировки ошибки (удалил проект с сервера с тем, чтобы развернуть снова), но речь в ней о том, что отсутствует файл settings.py. Мой вопрос скорее про то, как разумно решать проблему развертывания на сервере проекта, который был сделан локально.