# Django settings in multiple files

Tags: python, django

Всем привет!
Хочу сделать настройки для джанго и всех других библиотек в папке settings таким образом, что бы можно было их использовать вот так:

```
from django.conf import settings

print(settings.MY_VAR)
```

MY_VAR находится условно в mysite/mysite/settings/module_one

Перерыл весь гугл и нашел только django-split-settings, но есть цель сделать это без подобных библиотек.
Пробовал просто импортировать все в settings.**init**, но тогда возникает проблема циклического импорта.

Comment: в папке `settings` создайте `__init__.py` и импортируйте туда нужные файлы. все

Comment: @ZaArs а если из __init___.py в какой-то модуль настроек импорт будет?

Comment: Благодаря `__init__.py` в коде в других местах ничего не придется менять.

Comment: Напрямую не относится к вопросу, но, может, даст пищу для размышлений: [Как сделать несколько конфигураций (settings.py) для проекта Django?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747839)

Comment: А откуда и почему у вас возник циклический импорт — не очень понятно. Если делать всё аккуратно и следить за порядком инициализации, то циклических импортов быть не должно

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример. Не забудьте поправить BASE_DIR.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нельзя ли этот пример привести в виде кода, а не скриншота? Выглядит немного мелко, да и не всем хочется открывать пикчу, чтобы оттуда все переписывать

Comment: не надо ничего оттуда переписывать)