# Как продолжить работу с Django сайтом

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Дело в том, что я создал *django* сайт на своём компьютере и чтобы он работал на хостинге (*sprinthost*) пришлось хорошенько его переделать под него (добавить другую бд, установить куча библиотек, изменить настройки статики и медии и т.д.).

В общем я его загрузил и сижу сейчас довольный, но проблема в том, что мне приходится делать обновления для него и мне крайне неудобно делать это прямо через хостинг и консоль в putty + это крайне непрофессионально, так как все изменения применяются сразу к настоящему сайту.

И мне нужно найти способ как продолжить разработку сайта.

Есть такой вариант, что мне надо скачивать **zip архив** сайта на свой компьютер, менять кучу настроек чтобы он заработал на моём компе, потом начинать непосредственно разработку обновлений через удобную мне среду PyCharm, потом опять менять кучу настроек уже под хостинг (и бог знает импортируются ли изменения в бд) и заливать на хостинг.

Так вот есть какой-нибудь более простой и правильный способ продолжить работу над сайтом?

Comment: Настройки нужно хранить локально, например в переменных окружения.

Comment: Параметры, зависящие от окружения, нужно хранить и настраивать отдельно от остального проекта. Параметры БД, статики и медии должны записываться в локальный файл настроек или переменные окружения; куча библиотек — в файле setup.py или requirements.txt чтобы можно было их установить одной командой pip install.

Comment: [Как сделать несколько конфигураций (settings.py) для проекта Django?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747839)

Comment: А, и ещё по возможности рекомендую собирать весь Django-проект (за вычетом локальных настроек) в один whl-пакет. Тогда загрузка обновления на хостинг будет состоять из пяти простых шагов: 1) Сборка whl; 2) Загрузка whl на хостинг; 3) pip install этого whl-файла; 4) запуск migrate; 5) запуск collectstatic — и готово.